How to restrict `Cosmos DB Built-in Data Contributor` role assignment to a specific database or containers within an Cosmos DB account?
How to restrict an Cosmos DB Built-in Data Contributor role assignment to a specific database or container within an Cosmos DB account?
I'm using the same Cosmos DB account for multiple databases, but need to grant principals access to only a subset of these. As seen below, the Cosmos DB Built-in Data Contributor grant access to all containers within all databases.
How can I restrict the role assignment to only grant access to, say, a set of databases or, even more granular, a set of containers within an account?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/security/how-to-grant-data-plane-role-based-access?tabs=built-in-definition%2Ctypescript&pivots=azure-interface-cli
az cosmosdb sql role definition show --resource-group lab --account-name cosmosdb-test --id 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002 --output json
{
  "assignableScopes": [
    "/subscriptions/13113f84-1f44-4605-a65f-52ad8f926abf/resourceGroups/lab/providers/Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/cosmosdb-test"
  ],
  "id": "/subscriptions/13113f84-1f44-4605-a65f-52ad8f926abf/resourceGroups/lab/providers/Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/cosmosdb-test/sqlRoleDefinitions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002",
  "name": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002",
  "permissions": [
    {
      "dataActions": [
        "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/readMetadata",
        "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases/containers/*",
        "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases/containers/items/*"
      ],
      "notDataActions": []
    }
  ],
  "resourceGroup": "lab",
  "roleName": "Cosmos DB Built-in Data Contributor",
  "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlRoleDefinitions",
  "typePropertiesType": "BuiltInRole"
}


anything you tried and facing error?

I tried changing "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases/containers/*" to a specific container, but that doesn't seem to work. Furthermore, this doesn't let me grant access to a database, but only a single container at a time (assuming it works for others)


How to restrict an Cosmos DB Built-in Data Contributor role assignment to a specific database or container within an Cosmos DB account?

To assign role at the scope of container or database level you need to pass that scope while assigning the role to a user.
--For database scope
/subscriptions/SubscriptionId/resourceGroups/RGName/providers/Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/CosmosAccountName/dbs/DatabaseName

For container scope
/subscriptions/SubscriptionId/resourceGroups/RGName/providers/Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/CosmosAccountName/dbs/DatabaseName/colls/ContainerName

I did it using PowerShell code like below:
$parameters = @{
    ResourceGroupName = "RGName"
    AccountName = "CosmosAccountName"
    RoleDefinitionId = "Role defination ID"
    PrincipalId = "28963402-e9f1-49d6-8783-bed5c01a64ba"
    Scope = "Scope at database/container level"
}    
New-AzCosmosDBSqlRoleAssignment @parameters

It assigned roles as both container and database level as below:


Thank you! How did you figure this out? The documentation link in my question doesn't address database or container scopes. Do you know whether it's possible to do this in the Azure portal?
